# How should I fix my loop?

Tags: java

I am working on Bank Account assignment. It seems like I got the logic right but it does not produce the right output. I think the loop does not understand what I am trying to tell it to do. Do I place methods called at the wrong place? I have attached a sample output. I appreciate your helps! Thank you

```
 /**
 * This program prints a payoff schedule for a bank customer.
  Input: Account number, name of customer, and account balance.
  Output: Prints payoff schedule that includes payment amount and new balance
  until the account will be paid off. A customer must pay off their account when
  the balance reaches $10 or less. 1.2% interest is added at the beginning of
  each month and the customer then makes a payment equal to 5% of the current balance. 
  */

public class DT_BankAccount
{
 private String accountNum;
 private String customerName;
 private double customerBalance;
 double interest = 0.00; // Start out with 0.00 value for the customer.
 double payment = 0.00; // Start out with 0.00 value for the customer.

/**
* Constructor: Constructs a payoff schedule for a bank customer including account number, name of customer, and account balance.
* @param account number - the account number of the customer
* @param name of customer - the customer's name of the bank account
* @param account balance - the account balance of the customer
*/

public DT_BankAccount(String accountNum, String customerName, double customerBalance)
{
 // Initialize constructors
    this.accountNum = accountNum; 
    this.customerName = customerName;
    this.customerBalance = customerBalance;
}

 /**
  * This method calculates interest and return the balance times the 1.2% interest: the balance times the 1.2% interest
  * @return the balance times the 1.2% interest
  */
public double CalculateInterest()
{ 
  return interest = customerBalance * 0.012;
}

   /**
   * This method calculates new balance adds the interest to the balance
   */
 public void CalculateNewBalance()
 {
   payment = customerBalance + interest;
 }

 /**
  * This method calculates new payment returns the balance times 5%: the balance times 5% 
  * @return the balance times 5% 
  */
public double CalculatePayment()
{ 
  return payment * 0.05;
}

 /**
  * This method updates the balance after the payment is made: the updated (newest) balance
  * @return the updated (newest) balance
  */
public double BalanceUpdated()
{ 
  return customerBalance = customerBalance + interest - payment;
}
}

 import javax.swing.JOptionPane; // import JOptionPane class

 public class DT_PayoffTester
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    // Declare and initialize variables.
    String accountNum;
  String customerName;
  String stringCustomerBalance;
  double customerBalance = 0.00;
    double controller = 10.00; // Controls while loop.


    // Get input.
    accountNum = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter account number: ");
    customerName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter customer's name: ");
    stringCustomerBalance = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter customer's balance: ");

  // Convert string to double.
    customerBalance = Double.parseDouble(stringCustomerBalance);

  // creates one instance of the BankAccoount class by calling it’s constructor.
  DT_BankAccount BA = new DT_BankAccount(accountNum,customerName,customerBalance);

    System.out.println(customerName + "\n");

    while (BA.BalanceUpdated() > controller)
  {
        // methods called
        BA.CalculateInterest();
        BA.CalculateNewBalance();
        BA.CalculatePayment();
        BA.BalanceUpdated();
        System.out.println("Payment: " + BA.CalculatePayment());
        System.out.println("New Balance: " + BA.BalanceUpdated() + "\n");
    } // End of while loop.
    System.out.println("Account Number: " + accountNum);
    System.out.println("Final Balance Amount: " + BA.BalanceUpdated());
    System.out.println("Loan Paid Off");

    System.exit(0);
   }
  }
```

Sample output:

```
Start of sample output 
Billie Gates
Payment: $12.02
New Balance: $228.39
Payment: $11.56
New Balance: $219.57
Payment: $11.11
New Balance: $211.09
Payment: $10.68
New Balance: $202.95
Payment: $10.26
New Balance: $195.11
Payment: $9.87
New Balance: $187.58
Payment: $9.49
New Balance: $180.34
```

Skip to the end of the sample output:

```
Payment: $ 0.62
New Balance: $11.92
Payment: $ 0.60
New Balance: $11.46
Payment: $0.58
New Balance: $11.02
Payment: $0.55
New Balance: $10.59
Payment: $0.53
New Balance: $10.18
Payment: $0.51
New Balance:$ 9.79
Account Number: 91234567
Final Balance Amount:$ 9.79
Loan Paid Off
```

My output (wrong one)

```
 Billie Gates

 Payment: 6.229872
 New Balance: -123.12

 Account Number: 123
 Final Balance Amount: -369.36
 Loan Paid Off
```

Comment: When `BA.BalanceUpdated()` <= 10.00, your loop will stop, is it the logic you desired? The first balance returned is already <= 10.00 ( it's `-123.12` ). Lots of improvements can be done, e.g. save the returned value to a variable instead of calling `BA.BalanceUpdated()` multiple times.

Comment: I dont know why the first new balance is a negative number!

Comment: Isn't it entered by user ?

Comment: The initial balance is entered in. Then it will use that balance to calculate the new balance. I dont see any calculation will produce a negative number. Its weird

Comment: What is the input value?

Comment: In the sample run, it is $237.56

Comment: Hint: The effect of the statement `BA.CalculatePayment();` is absolutely nothing.  What do you think this method will do?  What does it actually do?

Comment: I think it calculates the new payment

Comment: And what does it do with the new payment after it calculates it?

Comment: instead of it calculates payment = (customerBalance + interest) * 0.05 at the same time, can I break it down into 2 methods?

Comment: See the calculation below.

Answer (score 1):

Here comes the mathematics:

Input: 237.56

Loop 1:

> In `BA.BalanceUpdated()` of `while` loop, `customerBalance` is set to `customerBalance`, as `interest` and `payment` are still 0. `customerBalance` is 237.56, which is > 10.00, loop continues.
>
> In `BA.CalculateInterest()`, `interest` is set to 237.56 x 0.012 =
>   2.85072
>
> In `BA.CalculateNewBalance()`, `payment` is set to 237.56 + 2.85072 =
>   240.41072
>
> In `BA.CalculatePayment()`, it does nothing on the first call (as you
>   don't use the returned value).
>
> In the 2nd `BA.CalculatePayment()`, it returns to 240.41072 x 0.05 = 12.020536, but it does not assign to any variable.
>
> In the 2nd `BA.BalanceUpdated()` in your print line, `customerBalance` is set to 240.41072 +
>   2.85072 - 240.41072 = 2.85072

Loop 1 Complete

Then your `while` checks if `BA.BalanceUpdated()` returns > 10.00, at this moment you executed this function 2nd time, which set `customerBalance` to 2.85072 + 2.85072 - 240.41072 = -234.70928, which is < 10.00. `while` loop breaks.

Thus, check your maths logic.

Answer (score 0):

First point:

In a case like this my general suggestion would be to perform a 'desk check'; manually execute your code on some sample data using pen and paper.  That is to say, starting with some value go through your code and for each line perform the calculations and record the state of all variables after each line.  This Can be time consuming but it works.

Second point:

It seems you may not realise that each time you call `BalanceUpdated()` the value of `customerBalance` will be changed.  If you call the method in the loop condition or if you call it within `System.out.println()` it still changes the value.  By the end of a single execution of this while loop interest has been added and payment subtracted three times.